# Excel Filter with Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write one macro it should work like Excel filter.  After getting all the data using this filter I want to paste in to the new worksheet.

Comment: You should try recording a macro for things like this.  Then adjust the code to suit.

Answer (score 1):

This sub filter zero values in sheet1 and copy to sheet2 range A1

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
'Developer by Bruno Leite
'http://officevb.com

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim FilterRange As Range

'Set your Sheet
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'Verify if is Filter

If Sht.FilterMode Then
      Sht.ShowAllData
End If

'Filter Column A with 0 at parameter
Sht.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"

'Define Range Of Visible cells without row title
Set FilterRange = Sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

FilterRange.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

Sht.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

[]´s